# The Copy to Clipboard doesn't work well in iPhone. Javascript

Tags: javascript, iphone, frontend

I have the following code:

```
<div>
  <div id="copy-number"><?php echo $account_number;?></div> 
  <button type="button" class="btn-copy2"><i class="icon-copy icon--md"></i></button>
</div>
```

Javascript part is:

```
btn_copy2.addEventListener('click',()=>{
            var copyText = document.getElementById("copy-number").innerHTML;
            unsecuredCopyToClipboard(copyText);
        });
/*COPY INSECURE TO CLIPBOARD*/
const unsecuredCopyToClipboard = (text) => {
            const textArea = document.createElement("textarea"); 
            textArea.value=text; 
            document.body.appendChild(textArea); 
            var range,selection;
            if (isOS()) {
                range = document.createRange();
                range.selectNodeContents(textArea);
                selection = window.getSelection();
                selection.removeAllRanges();
                selection.addRange(range);
                textArea.setSelectionRange(0, 999999);
                console.log("İOS");
            } 
            else {textArea.select();}//Android is OK
            document.execCommand('copy');
            document.body.removeChild(textArea);
            window.scrollTo(0, 0);/*EN alta gidiyordu..*/

        };
```

I want to copy a div content as number. The div contains only number. According to my code which below works well in Android and web.
It needs to be copied '1395904915'
But iPhone copied to clipboard like this:
----<a .href="tel:1395904915">1395904915</a.>---
You can check error photos:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dqgld.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTbLe.png)